# GWT Window.ClosingHandler catch required url

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, browser

Is there a way to fire the Window.ClosingHandler only if needed?
Inside my entry point I added the following code in order to have a popup telling the customer if he click on an external link he will get out from the page.

```
public static void addWindowClosingHandler(){
    Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {
        public void onWindowClosing(Window.ClosingEvent closingEvent) {
            closingEvent.setMessage("Are you sure you want to proceed?");
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is it fires even if I try to download a content from my page. I then need to understand if the called page is outside the site or if the required page is internal.
Is there a way to understand which will be the landing page?

Comment: Either by url or maintain some flags :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I have no control about the url cause it can be fired from wherever, and I would prefer do not keep track of the operation with a ugly static flag if possible...if there isn't any other solution than I probably would go for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon how you are trying to download a file. If you simply open a new window to download file it will help you to avoid firing window close handler.

```
    Button downloadBtn = new Button("Download File");
    downloadBtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Window.open("http://urlforfiledownload", "download", "");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Good idea, but...it opens a blank empty page with the downloaded file and it's not so nice to see...I would prefer keeping the download in the same page if possible.

Comment: @Lorenzo In that case you can simply replace `_blank` by `download` which will close new window once file download starts. I am updating the answer, if you accept it mark it as accepted :)

Comment: that's what i was looking for!! Thank you very much! I edited the answer in order to add the solution and accepted it!

Answer (score 0):

At the end I found another suitable solution, even if probably I will end up using the "_blank" solution provided by @Ajax.

In this link https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/Y9hnPFtySuU is described a different way to download the document, using an iframe. Steps should be:

1) include an iframe inside the activity where you know it's going to be fired the download action.

2) on download button is pressed just give the url to the iframe with a blank target.

That would be a good solution apart for the case where the browser decide to open the content inside the frame instead of downloading it. In that case it would appear as a bug. Therefore i probably will accept the "_blank" solution as the best one.